# how do i make google search result recognize my website language or font?

Tags: html

A website I made has got contents in Malayalam language, which includes heading tags,So when searched on google for this website the search results show gibberish as headings in search result. I used a font-family not recognised by google. Is there a work around for this? or do I have to use some other font recognised by google?. When the website is opened everything is shown correctly, only problem is in google search results.
[image: How its shown in google results]

Answer (score 1):

You can define your language in the html tag. For Malayalam it is "ml".

`<html lang="ml">`

Also, it's recommended to encode your files with UTF-8 and set that in the `head`-section as a meta-tag: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: It didn't help, the problem was that google couldn't recognise the font-family i used.